# do-release-upgrate Bionic to Focal is crashing with an error

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to do a release upgrade from Bionic to Focal. The upgrade is crashing pretty early with this error message

```
2023-08-29 04:47:19,413 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'python3.8-minimal': 'installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139'
2023-08-29 04:47:19,415 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() python3.8-minimal: installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
2023-08-29 04:47:20,545 ERROR Exception during pm.DoInstall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5aytfmug/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 220, in run
res = pm.do_install(self.writefd)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As additional repo I have the ondrej ppa for php, since I need different php versions on the system.

Here are the logs if it helps: [Logs](https://cloud.aria-network.com/index.php/s/89QzLCKyHskaBKE)

Can someone point me in the right direction ? Also, if there is a better place to ask this question, like github, please let me know

Comment: @waltinator It's true that we don't support 18.04 any more because it's EoSS, however, according to the *Questions you should avoid* section of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions regarding Ubuntu releases past their "End of Standard Support" or "End of Life" dates (whichever is earlier) **unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release**."* So questions about upgrading from unsupported releases, like this one, are perfectly fine and should not be closed as off-topic.

Comment: The upgrade has completed. Can you try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt install -f`? If they both work, then you don't need to worry, you're done. If they still error out with Python packages, can you post that log?